# Apache Mod php folders to php get

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve some url rewriting but i'm a bit lost..

I have a rewrite rule that transforms www.mysite.com/news/222 to www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=news&id=222 which is fine.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z])/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

Now, how can i rewrite so even if there is a direct access to the script, like www.mysite.com/index.php?cat=news&id=222, how can i rewrite this to www.mysite.com/news/222 ?

edit: edited cause i made a mistake, it was the other way around lol sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that does makes sense :)

No need to add another rule, this takes care of both sides : it builds the pretty URL and passes the variables to PHP script.

For the location, try putting the .htaccess this rule on your DocumentRoot folder as defined in your VirtualHost.